# Installing Plesk 12.5 on Ubuntu 14.04, setting up correct hostname?

Tags: ubuntu, plesk, hostname

I am trying to install Plesk 12.5.3 on fresh VPS running Ubuntu 14.04. Im using http://vultr.com (similar to digitalocean.com) etc

The part I am struggling with is what to put in the `/etc/hosts/` and 
`/etc/hostname` as this is required for the Plesk install.

Say my main domain name is `hello.com` and I want to have the plesk panel sit at `server.hello.com`

`ubuntu-server` is the name I have given my droplet

**Default `/etc/hostname`**

```
ubuntu-server
```

**Default** **`/etc/hosts`** :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       guest

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

127.0.0.1 guest
::1       guest

127.0.0.1 ubuntu-server
::1       ubuntu-server
```

What do I need to change this to? Do I need all of the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up working it out.

In my `/etc/hostname` I needed

```
server.hello.com
```

In my `/etc/hosts` I needed this:

```
127.0.0.1       server.hello.com server localhost.localdomain localhost
IP.OF.SEVER.HERE    server.hello.com     server
```